# Assign by reference PHP misunderstaning

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Whats the meaning of $arr[0] result "2"  in the code given below, $arr2 is copying $arr and increasing its first value by one, so the result of $arr2[0] "2" is understaning,but whats happening with $arr, when i pass by reference $arr[0] to $a like so $a=&$arr[0] the result of $arr[0] is 2, when i pass it by value $a=$arr[0[ the result of $arr[0] would be set to 1 as it should, can anyone enlighten me on this?

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$arr = array(1);
$a = &$arr[0];
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++;
echo $arr[0]. "<br>";//2
echo $arr2[0]. "<br>";//2
?>
```

Comment: $arr2[0]++; adds one

Comment: i know $arr2[0] is increasing by one but what that has to do with $arr[0]?

Comment: Is it because `$arr2[0]` is effectively the value of `$arr[0]` which was passed by reference to `$a` but somehow that reference has been passed into `$arr2` also? (Just guessing here)

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References in PHP are not like pointers; when you assign or pass something by reference, you create what we might call a "reference set" where *both* variables are references to the same "zval" (the structure in memory which holds the type and value of a variable).

An important consequence of this is that references are *symmetrical*. I tend to write assign by reference as `$foo =& $bar` rather than `$foo = &$bar` to emphasise this: the operator doesn't just take a reference to `$bar` and put it into `$foo`, it affects *both* operands.

With that in mind, let's go through your example:

```
$arr = array(1);
```

This will create two zvals: one for the array `$arr` itself, and one for the value in position `0` of that array (`$arr[0]`).

```
$a =& $arr[0];
```

This binds `$a` and `$arr[0]` into a reference set. Whichever of those names we use, we will be using the same zval that was previously created, and currently holds `1`.

```
$arr2 = $arr;
```

This copies the contents of `$arr` into a new array zval, `$arr2`. But it doesn't resolve the references inside that array into values, it just copies *the fact that they are a reference*.

So `$arr2[0]` is now also part of the reference set containing `$arr[0]` and `$a`.

```
$arr2[0]++;
```

This increments the zval pointed to by our reference set, from `1` to `2`.

```
echo $arr[0]. "<br>";//2
echo $arr2[0]. "<br>";//2
```

Since these are both part of the same reference set, they both point to the same zval, which is integer 2.

---

The inevitable question is, "bug or feature?" A more useful example would be passing an array containing references into a function:

```
function foo($array) {
   $array[0] = 42;
   $array[1] = 69;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
$foo = [ &$a, &$b ];
foo($foo);
echo $a; // 42
echo $b; // 69
```

Like assignment, passing into the function didn't break the references, so code manipulating them can safely be re-factored into multiple functions.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a bug but `var_dump()` can help to explain.

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$arr = array(1);

var_dump( $arr );
$a = &$arr[0];
var_dump( $arr );

$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++;
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
}
```

Take note of `&int(1)` in the second `var_dump()`. This tells us that position #0 of `$arr` has been turned into a reference pointer to a position in PHP's memory instead of remaining a dedicated value.

So when you perform `$arr2 = $arr;`, `$arr2` receives that reference pointer as well.

Comment: Is not quite clear why is happening yet but your answer helps, thanks

Comment: @ÇlirimMurati You're welcome. Unfortunately, it has behaved like this since PHP 4.3 from my testing so I doubt the PHP team is going to change this without an [**RFC**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto).

Comment: @ÇlirimMurati Please see the [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992971/2191572) to your question and definitely feel free to accept that one instead of mine.